# Advanced filling of prev and next buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

In a hidden list I have a variable list with this data (in this example **www.domain.com/2009** is the current URL):

```html
<ul id="WalkingYears" style="visibility: hidden; display:none;">
    <li id="Walk2011"><a href="http://domain.com/2011" title="2011"><img src="some-imga.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2010"><a href="http://domain.com/2010" title="2010"><img src="some-imgs.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2008"><a href="http://domain.com/2008" title="2008"><img src="some-imgf.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2007"><a href="http://domain.com/2007" title="2007"><img src="some-imgg.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2006"><a href="http://domain.com/2006" title="2006"><img src="some-imgh.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2005"><a href="http://domain.com/2005" title="2005"><img src="some-imgj.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2004"><a href="http://domain.com/2004" title="2004"><img src="some-imgk.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2003"><a href="http://domain.com/2003" title="2003"><img src="some-imgl.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2002"><a href="http://domain.com/2002" title="2002"><img src="some-imgz.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="Walk2001"><a href="http://domain.com/2001" title="2001"><img src="some-imgx.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

The above list is auto-generated and I can change this if I like; for example into:

```html
<div id="Walk2011" data-target="http://domain.com/2011" data-img="some-imga.jpg" data-title="2011"></div>
<div id="Walk2010" data-target="http://domain.com/2010" data-img="some-imgs.jpg" data-title="2010"></div>
<div id="Walk2008" data-target="http://domain.com/2008" data-img="some-imgd.jpg" data-title="2008"></div>
<div id="Walk2007" data-target="http://domain.com/2007" data-img="some-imgf.jpg" data-title="2007"></div>
<div id="Walk2006" data-target="http://domain.com/2006" data-img="some-imgg.jpg" data-title="2006"></div>
<div id="Walk2005" data-target="http://domain.com/2005" data-img="some-imgh.jpg" data-title="2005"></div>
<div id="Walk2004" data-target="http://domain.com/2004" data-img="some-imgj.jpg" data-title="2004"></div>
<div id="Walk2003" data-target="http://domain.com/2003" data-img="some-imgk.jpg" data-title="2003"></div>
<div id="Walk2002" data-target="http://domain.com/2002" data-img="some-imgl.jpg" data-title="2002"></div>
<div id="Walk2001" data-target="http://domain.com/2001" data-img="some-imgz.jpg" data-title="2001"></div>
```

You see that the current URL (www.domain.com/2009) is not showing in this list.

Now I'd like to fill the prev and next navigation, based on the current url, using the values mentioned above (title, href, image src):

```html
<a href="http://domain.com/2008" title="2008" id="balk-prev-btn" class="prev-btn left">
    <img src="some-imgd.jpg" alt="2008">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/2010" title="2010" id="balk-next-btn" class="next-btn right">
    <img src="some-imgs.jpg" alt="2010">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</a>
```

I guess I need to

- first find out what the current URL is
- then compare it to the data in the list
- somehow point out the prev and next page

Also when having selected a certain variable (the name of a walker) the links in the list will be different and the URL will be **www.domain.com/walkername/2009**:

```html
<div id="Walk2011" data-target="http://domain.com/walkername/2011" data-img="some-imga.jpg" data-title="2011"></div>
<div id="Walk2010" data-target="http://domain.com/walkername/2010" data-img="some-imgs.jpg" data-title="2010"></div>
<div id="Walk2008" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2008" data-img="some-imgd.jpg" data-title="2008"></div>
<div id="Walk2007" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2007" data-img="some-imgf.jpg" data-title="2007"></div>
<div id="Walk2006" data-target="http://domain.com/walkername/2006" data-img="some-imgg.jpg" data-title="2006"></div>
<div id="Walk2005" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2005" data-img="some-imgh.jpg" data-title="2005"></div>
<div id="Walk2004" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2004" data-img="some-imgj.jpg" data-title="2004"></div>
<div id="Walk2003" data-target="http://domain.com/walkername/2003" data-img="some-imgk.jpg" data-title="2003"></div>
<div id="Walk2002" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2002" data-img="some-imgl.jpg" data-title="2002"></div>
<div id="Walk2001" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2001" data-img="some-imgz.jpg" data-title="2001"></div>
```

In this case the prev and next button should only show the links with the walker name in it :) and should look like this:

```html
<a href="http://domain.com/walkername/2006" title="2006" id="balk-prev-btn" class="prev-btn left">
    <img src="some-imgg.jpg" alt="2006">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/walkername/2010" title="2010" id="balk-next-btn" class="next-btn right">
    <img src="some-imgs.jpg" alt="2010">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</a>
```

Can someone help me?
tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if you have this layout, this script should do the job

```
<div id="Walk2011" data-target="http://domain.com/walkername/2011" data-img="some-imga.jpg" data-title="2011"></div>
<div id="Walk2010" data-target="http://domain.com/walkername/2010" data-img="some-imgs.jpg" data-title="2010"></div>
<div id="Walk2008" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2008" data-img="some-imgd.jpg" data-title="2008"></div>
<div id="Walk2007" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2007" data-img="some-imgf.jpg" data-title="2007"></div>
<div id="Walk2006" data-target="http://domain.com/walkername/2006" data-img="some-imgg.jpg" data-title="2006"></div>
<div id="Walk2005" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2005" data-img="some-imgh.jpg" data-title="2005"></div>
<div id="Walk2004" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2004" data-img="some-imgj.jpg" data-title="2004"></div>
<div id="Walk2003" data-target="http://domain.com/walkername/2003" data-img="some-imgk.jpg" data-title="2003"></div>
<div id="Walk2002" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2002" data-img="some-imgl.jpg" data-title="2002"></div>
<div id="Walk2001" data-target="http://domain.com/didnotwalk/2001" data-img="some-imgz.jpg" data-title="2001"></div>
```

jQuery based script:

```
var xlocation =  "http://www.domain.com/walkername/2009".match(/(\/[a-zA-Z]+\/)(\d+)/); //sorry for ugly regexp --> ["/walkername/2009", "/walkername/", "2009"], also here should be used window.location.href , but for example lets use static string;
        //find and filter only links which have 'walkername' in data-tagert
    $el = $('#WalkingYears div[id^=Walk]').filter(function(i,el){
        return $(el).attr('data-target').indexOf(xlocation[1]) > 0;
    }),
//sort if divs is scrambeled
    $elSorted = $el.sort(sorter);
    prev =  jQuery.grep($elSorted,function(el,i){
        return $(el).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1<xlocation[2]*1
    })
    next = jQuery.grep($elSorted,function(el,i){
        return $(el).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1>xlocation[2]*1
    })
    var sorter = function(a,b){
    var a = $(a).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1,
    b = $(b).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1
    return b-a
    }

    //ADD href to buttons...
    $('#balk-prev-btn').prop('href',$(prev).first().attr('data-target'))
    $('#balk-next-btn').prop('href',$(next).last().attr('data-target'))
```

You`ll need to check if prevEl and NextEl still exists in case if current page is first or last. Also you will need to review regexp used for parsing url :)

Comment: Thank you @Arturas but I have no idea what to do now. I call this script using window.location.href and using the id's of the prev and next buttons but the links and titles (img src you didn't do I think?) do not get written in the prev and next links.

Comment: Try to run this code (http://pastebin.com/5CVtRbSu)  in this page http://herenloop.nl/maurice/2009. I`ve tested it in console and buttons where working fine.

Comment: @KestonPollard you can add img, and title (though some js in your page rewrites title on hover) in same manner as href was assigned.

Comment: Great stuff @Arturas, thanks. I succesfully added the img and title. However on http://herenloop.nl/2.aspx I used the xlocation http://herenloop.nl/2008 and that does not work. You have two different URL's the http://herenloop.nl/2008 ones, and the http://herenloop.nl/maurice/2008 ones. The second works.

Comment: @KestonPollard update a script a little bit, here is example with what was changed in comments http://pastebin.com/EDuS6iHB

Comment: Amazing @Arturas!! If you edit your answer-post, I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @KestonPollard i have updated an post with correct answer to question, didn`t add all examples we have discussed here because they are irrelevant for question rather suitable just for specific scenarios

Comment: mmm, problems here with caching in Chrome and the fact that the same script is called on all pages (same template). So we have to think about the rexexp, the filter and the stringvalue of xlocation...

Comment: @Keston  You have answer for question you've asked here and now as original question have diverged your problem is totally different from one you have posted here. Anyways if you need a solution i guess you need to ask new question how to make this logic to work on your site structure (whic was not specifies in qiestion itself)

Comment: I'm sorry but I did ask this in my original question @Arturas... "...In a hidden list I have a variable list with this data (in this example www.domain.com/2009 is the current URL..." and "...Also when having selected a certain variable (the name of a walker) the links in the list will be different and the URL will be www.domain.com/walkername/2009:..."

Comment: @KestonPollard Ok can you describe it more specifically, how many cases there are, as for now i assume there are 3 different scenarios:  1) startin page looks like domain.com/1.aspx domain.com/2.aspx, 2) next page might look domain.com/something/2009 3) next page might look domai.com/2009 ? If so, what should be shown in buttons for first case (where is no indication of year) ?  Or should script work only for 2nd and 3rd case? Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128828/discussion-between-keston-pollard-and-arturas-tamulaitis).

Comment: Did you see it @Arturas?